# Proof that the limit is 0 using Fourier series

Tags: integration, fourier-series

I have this problem and I guess I should solve it using Fourier because of the context:

let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  a continuous function over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\left|f\left(x\right)\right|\le x^4$ for all $x$.

Need to prove:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}\cos{\left(nx\right)}dx}=0$

I can see a connection to fourier coefficients and "riemann lebesgue" maybe but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\frac {f(x)} x$ for $0<x<\pi$ and $g(x)=\frac {f(\pi)} {\pi}$ fo $-\pi \leq x \leq 0$. Then $g$ is integrable and Riemann Lebesgue Lemma implies that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(x) \cos (nx)dx \to 0$. Hence the result. Integrability of $g$ comes from the given inequality (which shows that $g$ is bounded).

Comment: Hi, why did you choose $g(x)$ in the range $[-π,0]$ to be a constant? and why this specific one?

Comment: @ShiranShaharabani Actually any constan t would be fine. I just made it periodic.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The integrability of $g$ comes from the following? ${-x}^3\le\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}\le x^3$ ? but not every bounded function is integrable

Comment: @ShiranShaharabani Riemann Lebesgue Lemma does not require Riemann integrability. Lebesgue integrability is enough. Since $g$ is measurable and bounded on $[-\pi, \pi]$ it is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Got you, thanks a lot!